# service.getPort thowing NullPointerException JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am getting a **NullPointerException** when I call service.getPort(HelloInterface.class).

WebService:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.endpoints.HelloInterface")
public class HelloImpl implements HelloInterface{

    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");
    }
}


@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface HelloInterface {

    @WebMethod
    public void sayHello();

}
```

Client:

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8881/ws/service1?wsdl");
            QName qname = new QName("http://endpoints.com/", "HelloImplService");
            Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
            HelloInterface helloInterface = service
                    .getPort(HelloInterface.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:14)
```

While using wsgen on the command prompt I didn't receive any kind of output on command prompt.

Help is highly appreciated!!